# Confirm overwrite while loading file to server

Tags: php

I have a form that load file to server. File while loading changes the name by the selected date. I want to issue a confirmation when downloading a file, if such a file already exists and when clicking on the corresponding button, replace or not replace the file. To do this, I created a folder tmp in which I put temporary files. And in theory, when you click yes, the file from the temporary folder should overwrite the file in the main one.

```
<form>
    <label for="date">Дата</label><input type="date" id="date" name="date">
    <label for="customFile">Выбрать отчет</label>
    <input type="file" id="customFile" name="report">
    <button type="submit">Load file to server</button>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['date'])){
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'report');
$date = $_POST['date'];

if ($_FILES['report']['name'] != ''){

    $dir = 'report/';
    $report = $dir . $date . '.xlsx';
    $tmp = $dir . 'tmp/' . $date . '.xlsx';

    if (file_exists($report)) {
        require('include/file_exists.php');
        copy($_FILES['report']['tmp_name'], $tmp);
    } else {
        copy($_FILES['report']['tmp_name'], $report);
        echo "File loaded<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

This is my included file  "file_exists.php" :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['overwrite'])) {
    copy($tmp, $report);
    echo "File overwrite!<br>";
} else {
    echo "No button enter<br>";
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <div id="LoadReport">
        <p>Do you want to overwrite the file?</p>
        <button type="button">Нет</button>
        <button type="button" name="overwrite">Да</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Maybe my problem can be solved? I want my clients confirm overwrite the existing file while loading file to server

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: _“This is my included file "file_exists.php"”_ - included where, exactly?

Comment: @Dave - After clicking ok in "file_exists.php",  file does not overwrite. It's works on you?

Comment: @cbroe
HERE: if (file_exists($report)) {         require('include/file_exists.php');

Comment: You are sending a second form here, so there is no reason `$tmp` and `$report` should still exist at that point. You will either need to pass those value along with the form (potentially dangerous, a user manipulating the values could move completely different files than you intended to), or store them into a session (has potential for conflict, if the user has multiple such forms open in different tabs.)

Comment: Your logic of including this at that point is flawed. When you submit your original form, `$_POST['overwrite']` will not be set at this point. And after your second form gets submitted for confirmation, it will not go into that if branch any more, because now `$_FILES['report']['name']` will not be set any more - you uploaded the file in the previous request, not the current one.

Comment: @CBroe
I try to change it like that: copy('report/tmp/name.txt', 'report/name.txt');
But it doesn't work.

Your logic of including this at that point is flawed.
Do you have any ideas how to implement my requirements?

Comment: No, because replacing the variables with static values does not fix the underlying logic problem. You need to think about this a bit, which values and parameters will be available _when_ …

Comment: @cbroe 
Is there any clue where I can dig further?

Comment: I already mentioned two possible solutions …?